# php settings header location redirecting to paypal but query vars not passed (possibly)

Tags: php, redirect, paypal

so this is kind of wierd.

on 99.99% of servers this is being used it works just fine, but I have one , where it somehow does not want to work properly, so I wonder if there's a php settings (this server has also suhosin installed) that might prevent this from working.

scenario is this:

the script is (trying to) redirect to paypal like so:

```
  header('location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?'.http_build_query($varsToSendtoPaypal).'');
```

as i mentioned , this works just fine 99.99% of the time. even if i do

```
print'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?'.http_build_query($varsToSendtoPaypal).'';
```

and copy the resulting url into the browser it redirects as expected. 
however, when using the header method it DOES redirect, but only to the paypal homepage at paypal.com and not the checkout page .

Somehow I am  thinking that the query string gets truncated for some reason , but I have no idea where to look to find out if that is the case or what setting it may be that might affect this....

there are also only 22 variables in the query string with nothing out of the ordinary

any ideas / hints / pointers greatly appreciated

happy to expand of course if required..

PS: this script runs in a wordpess plugin btw, but I would have thought that has no bearing on why this would not work . just thought i'd mention it though

Comment: I'd recommend you use the browser console to track the redirect and find out the difference between the redirecting and your manual input

Comment: good point. I totally forgot about that possibility. i shall investigate

Answer (score 0):

so, thanks to msg7086 suggestion to have a look at the console, I tracked the error down to this particular server using `&amp;` as opposed to  just `&` when using http_build_query.

the fix for this appears to be using

```
http_build_query($array,'','&');
```

as opposed to just

```
http_build_query($array);
```

maybe this helps someone